# Gradle DSL method not found: 'testimplementation()'?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'testimplementation()'
```

The project 'My Project' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply gradle plugin

I have tried already tried

1. delete project's .gradle resynced
2. Invalidate/caches and  restart Use
3. local gradle distribution option

Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.techknocorp.a.metturcable"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 532016
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testimplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
 core:3.1.1'
    implementation files('libs/opencsv-2.3.jar')
}
```

Top level Gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Comment: Please try replace `testimplementation` by `testImplementation`

Comment: Yea it's helpful.but run window showing only 'task executed'.

Comment: Can you please add more details in your question?

Comment: Thank you... That's the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `testImplementation` instead of `testimplementation`.

```
dependencies {
    //....
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //..
}
```